# Minecraft: LAN options

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, hosting

My team and I are hosting a LAN-party this friday and we expect about 20 people to enter our Minecraft: Hunger Games contest.

The problem is that we have no firewall or router access, and all attendees will be on the same school network.

What is our best option for server setup? Do we rent one?
Running the bukkit from my computer is impossible, I need to port forward to let people on the server. If I open my games to LAN, no one can connect because of firewall configuration.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have permission to do this? It would make things much easier.

Comment: Your best bet would be to either have your own switches and/or routers.  Barring that, your school's IT help would do the trick.  Everything else is basically trying to bypass their protections.

Comment: I have permission, but the IT guy is absent and will not be able to forward the ports. I do control the switches, not the main router.

Comment: If you don't control the entire infrastructure, or have the help of the person who does, that's step 1.  You need one of those in order for this to succeed.

Answer (score 4):

If everyone is on the same LAN, you do not need to port forward in order to play.

You need to do two things:

First, find your local IP. For Windows, start **CMD as administrator**, type in **ipconfig** and press enter. Next to **IPv4 Address** should be something that looks like **192.168.1.X** where X is one ore more numbers. Remember this number, with the dots.

Next, start up your server.

Finally, have people connect to the IP you found earlier, 192.168.1.X.

Have fun!

Answer (score -1):

Back in the day when I didn't know the first thing about networking the only way I found to make certain games work in lan was using hamachi (https://secure.logmein.com/products/hamachi/download.aspx).

It easily sets up a vpn so you can pretend that everyone in it is in a LAN, but unfortunately it means you need all 20 of your guests to install it, unless you can do that yourself before they arrive.
I usually avoid it when possible but it seems like a good option when you have absolutely no access to any configs at all.
Oh and it's not really local, so you should test how well it works with 20 players in it. I think there should be no problems, but I've never tried it with more than a handful and you don't want to leave it up to chance, it's better to pay for a server rather than having lag.

Comment: I can't ask all 50 participants to download and install a program, and a vpn is generally slower. Yes, I need 20 spots at a time, but all 50 attendees will need access at some point.

Comment: Why downvote? my answer wasn't misleading.

Comment: I don't have the rep to downvote, I didn't do it